# SQL issues with aggregate functions and ordering

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm currently in the process of learning SQL, and I'm encountering a few problems so far. In particular this one : I have a University database (we will be using an EXAM table, but that really doesn't matter in this case).

I am trying to order the students by their average at finals.
It should look like this :

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, AVG(SCORE) AS AVG_SCORE FROM EXAM GROUP BY AVG_SCORE;
```

The terminal complains with a "not a single group function" most of the time, and in this case "invalid identifier". From what I understood, I cannot use two aggregate functions together, like

```
max(avg(score))
```

Why is that ? how to counter the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state the RDBMS you are using. So the following might not exactly fit to your needs...

You do not want to group by `AVG_SCORE`...

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, AVG(SCORE) AS AVG_SCORE 
FROM EXAM 
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY AVG_SCORE
```

What you really want is to group by `STUDENT_ID` in order to get the average per student.

The `ORDER BY` is able to use a column's alias...

Comment: Sql plus. Thanks Shnugo, my issue here is I didn't understand the difference between order by and group by. Makes sense now.